# I can't get the button to target the parent div and parent siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have weak jquery skills and its killing me. Deadline looms. So, I have this html:

```
<div class="productbox"><button>1</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>2</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>3</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>4</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>5</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>6</button></div>
<div class="productbox"><button>7</button></div>
```

Using this function

```
$(function() {
$(".productbox").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass( "expandthebox", 1500 ),   
   $(".productbox").not(this).removeClass("expandthebox", 1500); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

This works great, but the click is on the div rather than on the button within the div. I want the divs to expand just as they do from a click on the button (or pic) inside the div. I have come close to making it work with the click on "button" and $(this).parent.toggleclass but I can't seem to get the "removeClass" to work on the other div's.
So tired and cranky now, really hoping someone will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS.

Comment: You want to remove class name expandthebox from all the other divs except the div which is clicked?

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/47cw2oh2/) works fine

Comment: Yes, I want to click on the button within the box(div) and expand the size of that div and have all other shrink back to their original size. Here is the css:
   .productbox {
  float:left;
  width:16%;
  height:100px;
  background:#000;
  margin:5px;
  color:slate
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}

.expandthebox {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

Comment: Is this your desired effect? [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w42xLxLf/1/)

Comment: Here it is in action on codepen.
http://codepen.io/wpneily/details/wBKGKv

Comment: Yes, that is the effect but a click from the button only.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPGRxE, Might this help you

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
$(function() {
    $(".productbox button").click(function() {
        var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('.productbox');
        $parentDiv.toggleClass( "expandthebox", 1500 ),   
        $(".productbox").not($parentDiv).removeClass("expandthebox", 1500); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/47cw2oh2/1/)

Comment: Hmm. No this does not work as the other divs do not shrink back to original size after clicking on another div's button.

Comment: Wahoo! You Rock! Thank you so much. I really appreciate this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the parent's siblings and remove the class.

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("expandthebox", 1500);
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('expandthebox', 1500)
        return false;
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/47cw2oh2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the button has `class="clickme"`.

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.productbox').addClass('expandthebox', 1500);
});
```

You can expand from that.

I had a problem like this before, but this fixed it. Now let me explain. `.closest()` will take the closest item with `class="productbox"` , this means it will take it's parent, because It's closest, and it will always be. After it selects the parent, you are free to animate it.

Comment: How then do I remove the class from the sibling divs other than the one I have just clicked?

Comment: Oh, well, looks like I haven't read your post well. You can't really only if you try using a variable named toggle and then get a  couple of if/else() statements.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(function() {
$(".productbox").click(function() {
     $(".productbox").removeClass("expandthebox"); 
     $(this).addClass( "expandthebox", 1500 );  
    return false;
  });
});
```